# Entity Framework CTP4 Code First: Mapping protected properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, code-first

I would like to use a lazy-loading collection on a model, but I want Add/Remove functionality to be done through separate methods.  So something like this:

```
class Model
{
  protected virtual ICollection<Something> _somethings { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<Something> Somethings 
  { 
    get { return _somethings; } 
  }

  public void AddSomething(Something thingToAdd)
  {
    /*  logic */
    _somethings.Add(thingToAdd);
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to configure the mapping for this.  I looked into using a configuration class: EntityConfiguration.  But since the property is protected I can't figure out how to set a configuration on it.  Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Would something like a Repository work?

Comment: I guess you have similar problem like me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574333/ef-4-0-mapping-to-readonly-property-with-private-field

Answer (score 1):

You can use readonly static Expression for access to protected property like this

```
protected virtual ICollection<Something> _somesing { get; set; }
public static readonly Expression<Func<Model, ICollection<Something>>> Expression = p => p._something;

public IReadOnlyCollection<Something> Something
{
     return _sumething.AsReadOnly();
}
```

And use it in OnModelCreating method in DbContext class for mapping protected property

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().HasMany<Something>(Model.Expression);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you declare the configuration class (inheriting EntityConfiguration) inside your Model class, it could work. It's not a nice solution, since subclassing is generally discouraged, but it's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Ive heard this only can be done using EDMX file way.. not code first.