# Can I create a list that holds both a long and a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class BaseGridViewModel
{
    protected BaseGridViewModel()
    {
        Timer = new List<long>();
    }
    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
}
```

To update the timer I have:

```
vm.Timer.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I am not so familiar with lists. Is it possible for me to have a list that 
contains both a long and a string so that I could do the following:

```
vm.Timer.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, "After event 1");
vm.Timer.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, "After event 2");
```

Comment: One way would be to use a `List<Tuple<long, string>>` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Isn't a Tuple immutable though?  That would prevent the OP from updating values if they wanted/needed to.

Comment: @Tim Without alot of context, I would think this is a perfect place for an immutable type.

Comment: I would not need to update the values once they had been set. Could you possibly give me an example of how I could use this. Thanks

Comment: @Gemma http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097287/how-to-create-immutable-objects-in-c

Comment: @Gemma: have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx). Just create a `List<Tuple<long, string>>` and add it in this way: `timers.Add(Tuple.Create(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, "After event 1"));`. You get these values via `Item1` and `Item2` properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a class to hold the two values, and store them in the list instead.

```
public sealed class TimeEvent
{
  public long Elapsed {get; private set;}
  public string Description { get; private set;}
  public TimeEvent(long elapsedTime, string descriptionOfEvent)
  {
    this.Elapsed = elapsedTime;
    this.Description = descriptionOfEvent;
  }
}

public IList<TimeEvent> TimerEvents {get; set;}

vm.Timer.Add(new TimeEvent(sw.ElapsedMillisends, "After event 1"));
```

Comment: What do you think about the idea of using a Tuple as suggested in the comments?

Comment: @Gemma Tuples are fine in some cases but generally I prefer a class with named meaningful properties rather then Item1, Item2, ect.

Comment: And if you wanted to get *really* crazy you could even implement a collection class (e.g., `Timeline`) with a custom `Add` method plus some convenience methods/properties like `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `TotalElapsed`, etc.

Comment: @DanTao Add in some automatic database and xml serialization stuff and you have the tool I wrote to gather database performance metrics :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `class` and then create a `List` of that `class`.

```
public class TimerData
{
    public long time;
    public string description;

    public TimerData(long t, string d)
    {
        this.time = t;
        this.description = d;
    }
} 


List<EventData> list = new List<EventData>();
list.Add(new TimerData(50, "Description"));
```

There are more advanced things you could do with your class, but this method is simple.