# Entity Framework DbEntityEntry> 'Does not contain a definition for Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This code sniper is from [Adding CreatedDate to an entity using Entity Framework 5 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385477/adding-createddate-to-an-entity-using-entity-framework-5-code-first)

```
        public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        DateTime saveTime = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added))
        {
            if (entry.Property("CreateDate").CurrentValue == null)
                entry.Property("CreateDate").CurrentValue = saveTime;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();

    }
```

But on my solution I get this error "System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable 'Does not contain a definition for Where ...

Comment: Check that you have a using statement for System.Linq

Comment: You have `System.Linq` using statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm expecting that you are missing  `using System.Linq`

Comment: Thank you all I was missing System.Linq but VS was not able to resolve  it

Comment: try Resharper It's great tools for suggesting and resolving using assemblies  and organizing your code

Answer (score 0):

Try having your code in another method and call it in your SaveChanges method
something like this. just above your savechanges method write

```
private void MyRule() 
{
  DateTime saveTime = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added))
    {
        if (entry.Property("CreateDate").CurrentValue == null)
            entry.Property("CreateDate").CurrentValue = saveTime;
    }
 }
```

and then call it in your save changes like

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
 this.MyRule();
 return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This should do the trick :)

Cheers!